# Login with TokenAuthentication and AbstractBaseUser errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

my user model:

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), auto_now_add=True)
    national_code = models.CharField(
        _('national code'), max_length=10, blank=True, null=True
    )
    phone_number = models.CharField(
        _('phone number'), max_length=13, blank=True, null=True
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff'), default=False)
    avatar = models.ImageField(
        _('avatar'), upload_to='avatars', default='avatars/defaults.png'
    )
    age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_('age'), blank=True, null=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    @property
    def get_full_name(self):
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    @property
    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
```

user model manager:

```py
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

user serializer:

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id',
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'national_code',
            'phone_number',
            'age',
            'avatar'
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        for (key, value) in validated_data.items():
            setattr(instance, key, value)

        instance.save()
        return instance
```

login view:

```py
class LoginView(ObtainAuthToken):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.validated_data['user']
            token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

            return successful_response(
                messages=_('User Login Successfully'),
                data={
                    'token': token.key
                }
            )
        return unsuccessful_response(errors=serializer.errors)
```

in postman, I send username and password and receive this response:

```json
{
    "errors": {
        "non_field_errors": [
            "Unable to log in with provided credentials."
        ]
    }
}
```

I will send all the necessary parameters for logging in, I tried everything that came to my mind, but I could not solve the problem. I do not know the reason why I receive this error.Where does the problem come from I do not understand?

Comment: Shouldn't you be sending email + password since your `USERNAME_FIELD = email`

Answer (score 0):

I Added password field in UserSerializer and solve this problem.